# Patch forceDownload in Sitecore media types for PDF files

Tags: configuration

I want to patch only the `ForceDownload` attribute in below config:

```xml
<mediaLibrary>
    <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
            <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
            <forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
            <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/pdf</sharedTemplate>
            <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/pdf</versionedTemplate>
        </mediaType>
    </mediaTypes>
</mediaLibrary>
```

Please let me know, how to write the patch to make `ForceDownload` to `false`.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly shortened version of the config Marek Musielak suggested can be achieved using `patch:instead` to replace the node with a new one:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
          <forceDownload patch:instead="forceDownload">false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the original `forceDownload` element and insert new one with `false` value.

1. Create a patch file called `MediaType.Pdf.Disable.ForceDownload.config`.
2. Edit the file and enter the following xml:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
          <forceDownload>
            <patch:delete />
          </forceDownload>
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

3. Copy the file to `App_Config\Include` folder of your website or any of the subfolders of that folder.

More about patching can be read in the article:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/use-a-patch-file-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

To update element values like this, it's sufficient to just go down the unique path to the value you want to change, without specifying any `patch` attribute. This works just fine:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file">
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```